# argument to operation or instruction has illegal size 8086 subroutine

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I started programming in assembler for microprocessor 8086. I try to draw a tree on the screen, sending a subroutine, row, column, amount (collected from the stack), the error I present is

> argument to operation or instruction has Illegal size

on line 21,  ie when performing the push count,column,row.

```
DATOS SEGMENT
row DB 1
colum DB 39
carac DB 2AH
count DB 1
ENDS
PILA SEGMENT STACK
    DB 100 DUP(?)
PILA ENDS
CODIGO SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODIGO , DS:DATOS,SS:PILA
INICIO :
    MOV AX,DATOS
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV AH,00h ;Clear 
    MOV AL,03h
    INT 10h

HACER : 

        PUSH   count ; LINE ERROR
        PUSH   colum ; LINE ERROR
        PUSH   row   ;LINE ERROR
        CALL DIBUJA ; CALL PROC DIBUJA
        DEC colum
        ADD count,2
        CMP colum ,0 ; LINE ERROR
        JAE HACER
        POP AX

FIN : MOV AH,4CH
      INT 21H

DIBUJA PROC 
    PUSH AX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH DX
    MOV BP,SP
    ADD BP ,8
    MOV DH, [BP]  ; ACCESS TO ROW
    ADD BP,2
    MOV DL,[BP]   ; ACCES TO COLUMN
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 10H
    MOV BH,0   ; PAGE
    MOV AL,2AH  ; CHAR * HEXADECIMAL
    MOV AH,0AH
    ADD BP,2  ; ACCES TO COUNT
    MOV CX, [BP] ; COUNT 
    INT 10H

    POP DX
    POP CX
    POP BX
    POP AX
    RET
DIBUJA ENDP

CODIGO ENDS
END INICIO
```

Comment: You can't push a single byte on the stack using `push`. You could change all the variables to `DW` instead. That may be the simplest.

Comment: What suggestion would you give me? Move it to a record before doing the push?

Comment: You could also override the pushes to use a word by doing something like `push word ptr [count]`. The top 8 bits will be junk.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, it works but apparently erroneously access to the amount sent by parameter. Maybe I'm getting the column or row value? Or could I recommend another way to access the parameters of the subroutine without using BP?

Comment: You should step through with a debugger to watch what is happening. Your function pushes 4 registers for a total of 8 bytes. The return address takes 2 bytes as well. First parameter would be at BP+10. Also unclear what this line is doing `JMP colum ,0` that doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: If it was editing error was CMP, I want it to fill with * until columa is> = 0, the BP +10 what parameter would it take? sorry for the inconvenience. .

Comment: BP+0 would be saved value of DX, BP+2 is CX, BP+4 is BX, BP+6 is AX, BP+8 is return address pushed by _CALL_, BP+10 is row, BP+12 is colum, BP+14 is count.

Comment: Just a note - when I said _You can't push a single byte on the stack using push_ I meant that in the context of a memory operand. On the 80186+ it is possible to push an immediate value on the stack that is a byte but it is pushed as a word where the byte is sign extended to the size of a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> PUSH   count ; LINE ERROR
> PUSH   colum ; LINE ERROR
> PUSH   row   ;LINE ERROR
> ```

You get an "illegal size" error because the `push` instruction can't deal with a byte-sized memory access. A solution is to first move the byte sized variable in the low byte of a 16-bit general register and then push that. The fact that the high byte will contain garbage is of no importance:

```
mov  al, count
push ax
mov  al, colum
push ax
mov  al, row
push ax
```

---

There are some more issues with your program:

- The BIOS SetCursor function also requires the `BH` register to contain the display page for which you want to set the cursor. Move the `mov bh,0` instruction a few lines up in your program.
- The *DIBUJA* procedure pushes a lot of registers, yet you forget to preserve the `BP` register that you use.
- Setting BP=8 gives access to the return address, where you want access to the arguments. In your code you'll find the 1st arg (*row*) at [bp+10].
- Each time you call the procedure you push some values on the stack. Upon returning you need to remove these from the stack else a stack overflow will harm your program. There are 2 ways to solve this:

  - Have the procedure do it by writing as its last instruction:

    ```
    ret 6
    ```
  - Add the stackpointer after returning from the call:

    ```
    call DIBUJA
    add  sp, 6
    ```
- There's a superfluous `pop ax` right before the *FIN* label.
- When you wrote `cmp colum, 0` `jae HACER`, you effectively wrote an **infinite loop** because every value in the variable *colum* will ALWAYS BE ABOVE OR EQUAL TO ZERO. You could have gotten away with it had you treated the *colum* variable a signed quantity and used the signed branch `jge HACER` (jump on greater or equal).

---

### Putting it all together.

```
HACER: 
    mov  al, count
    push ax
    mov  al, colum
    push ax
    mov  al, row
    push ax
    CALL DIBUJA
    inc  row          ; See final note!
    DEC  colum
    ADD  count, 2
    CMP  colum, 16    ; See final note!
    JAE  HACER
FIN:
    MOV  AH,4Ch
    INT  21h

DIBUJA PROC 
    PUSH AX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH DX
    push bp
    MOV  BP, SP
    MOV  DH, [BP+12]  ; ROW
    MOV  DL, [BP+14]  ; COLUMN
    MOV  BH, 0        ; PAGE
    MOV  AH, 02h
    INT  10h
    MOV  CX, [BP+16]  ; COUNT 
    MOV  AX, 0A2Ah    ; "*"
    INT  10h
    pop  bp
    POP  DX
    POP  CX
    POP  BX
    POP  AX
    RET  6            ; +6 to remove the 3 words that were pushed as arguments
DIBUJA ENDP
```

---

### A final note.

To obtain a descent tree shape on the 80x25 textscreen, you should

- stop the main loop when *colum* reaches 16. Going as low as 0 will fill the screen with garbage!
- increment the *row* because now everything gets displayed on the row 1.

Comment: @DarkFenix. You definitely should accept this answer. It's as high quality as it can be! It's CodeReview material.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much for the delay in accepting it.