# How can I draw an upright triangle of asterisks aka stars?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I am a bachelor's degree student in computer science and I wanted to know how to change this assembly code with the `gotoxy x,y` command to show the stars in the output as shown in the picture below.

[image: here]

```
nextline macro
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,13
    int 21h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h
endm

gotoxy macro x,y
     mov dl,x
     mov dh,y
     mov bh,0
     mov ah,2
     int 10h
endm
.MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 64

 .DATA
   msg1  DB  'Enter a number : $'
   msg2  DB  'Wrong number!!$'
   n     db  ?
   x     db  0
   y     db  0

 .CODE
   MAIN:
     MOV AX, @DATA             
     MOV DS, AX
l3:
     LEA DX, msg1           
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     MOV AH, 1                
     INT 21H
     cmp al,'1'
     jl  l4 
     cmp al,'9'
     jg  l4
     jmp l5  
     
l4:  nextline
     LEA DX, msg2           
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H 
     nextline
     jmp l3 

l5:  sub al,'0'
     mov n,al

     mov cl,1 
l1:  
     mov ch,1
l2:

     mov al,n
     sub al,ch
     mov x,al
     mov y,cl
     gotoxy x,y      
     mov dl,'*'
     mov ah,2
     int 21h
     inc ch
     cmp ch,cl
     jle l2

     inc cl
     cmp cl,n
     jle l1     

          
     MOV AH, 4CH                 
     INT 21H

END MAIN
```

Comment: Get an idea to draw your tree studying [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584877/argument-to-operation-or-instruction-has-illegal-size-8086-subroutine?r=SearchResults&s=3|23.5365) It's has the code of your *gotoxy* inlined, so you could choose to replace that by your macro.

Comment: There's not much point in naming the args to `gotoxy` if you're going to always inefficiently pass labels to static storage anyway, instead of `al` and `cl` to let the macro `mov` them from where you have them.  And BTW, using a macro hides a missed optimization: after it runs, AH=2 so you could omit the `mov ah,2` after it: BIOS cursor-position and DOS char-output happen to use the same function numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps if you make a table with what you want to see on the screen:

| row | indentation | asterisks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 5 | 0 | 9 |

and then see the regularity of it all and how to produce the numbers knowing that `n=5`:

| row | indentation | asterisks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 = (n - 1) | 1 = (1 + 1) - 1 |
| 2 | 3 = (n - 2) | 3 = (2 + 2) - 1 |
| 3 | 2 = (n - 3) | 5 = (3 + 3) - 1 |
| 4 | 1 = (n - 4) | 7 = (4 + 4) - 1 |
| 5 | 0 = (n - 5) | 9 = (5 + 5) - 1 |
|  |  |  |
| row | n - row | row + row - 1 |

```
     mov cl, 1     ; Row from 1 to 5
T1:
     mov al, n     ; Indentation AL = (n - row)
     sub al, cl
     mov x, al     ; \
     mov y, cl     ; |
     gotoxy x,y    ; / This could easily become "GOTOXY AL, CL",
                   ;   no longer needing the x and y variables
     mov dl, '*'
     mov bl, cl    ; Number of asterisks BL = (row + row - 1)
     add bl, cl
     dec bl
T2:
     mov ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
     int 21h
     dec bl
     jnz T2

     inc cl        ; Next row
     cmp cl, n
     jbe T1
```